# Unable to run ant.zip/ ant.tar task in the jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ant, jenkins-workflow

I am trying to run the ant zip task in my pipeline script. But it is throwing an error:

```
Problem creating zip: /abc.zip (Permission denied) (and the archive is probably corrupt but I could not delete it)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Zip.executeMain(Zip.java:741)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Zip.execute(Zip.java:568)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /abc.zip (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
```

I am however trying to do the same using the command line on the windows machine where I have installed groovy. When I able to run the ant task...

My pipeline script goes like this :

```
    def createArtifacts() {
        def root = pwd()
        def services = ["abc", "def"].toArray()

        for (int i = 0; i < services.size(); i++) {
            dir(root + "\\src\\" + services[i]) {
                echo("Trying to create zip package")

                def ant = new AntBuilder()
                ant.zip(destfile: "${services[i]}.zip", basedir: 'bin')
            }
        }
    }

    node('windows') {
        stage 'Archive artifacts'
        createArtifacts()
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to save your files in root directory, `/`. What is this  `AntBuilder`? Is it part of Jenkins API or 3rd party Plug-in? Please by aware that Ant plugin is currently [unsupported](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md) by Jenkins Pipeline.

Comment: AntBuilder is a helper class of groovy to execute ant tasks. I was not aware that Ant plugin is supported by Jenkins pipeline . Does it mean I cannot use this helper class in groovy ? 

Also, I am not trying to save my file in root directory. I used root as a variable to get the current working directory and this method needs to run in multiple folders.  I tried running the same script from the console of the machine and it works as expected. Just that through Jenkins it is throwing up the error.

Comment: Check Windows user accounts which are used to run Jenkins slave and run script from command line. Are they different?

Comment: Nope, they are the same users.. I run the Jenkins slave as Administrator.